# Como enviar List<T> com KvmSerializable?

Tags: android

Estou implementando KvmSerializable para comunicação com webservice com tipos complexos.

Tenho uma propriedade do tipo List. Porém estou indicando o tipo List.class e não está chegando essa lista lá no webservice.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
public class CadastrosImpGarIn implements KvmSerializable {

public int codCli;
public int codEmp;
public int codFil;
public int codMot;
public String datCol;
public String flowInstanceID;
public String flowName;
public String numDoc;
public List<CadastrosImpGarInTabBat> tabBat;

@Override
public Object getProperty(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return codCli;
    case 1:
        return codEmp;
    case 2:
        return codFil;
    case 3:
        return codMot;
    case 4:
        return datCol;
    case 5:
        return flowInstanceID;
    case 6:
        return flowName;
    case 7:
        return numDoc;
    case 8:
        return tabBat;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 8;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable hash, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "codCli";
        break;
    case 1:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "codEmp";
        break;          
    case 2:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "codFil";
        break;
    case 3:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "codMot";
        break;
    case 4:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "datCol";
        break;
    case 5:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "flowInstanceID";
        break;
    case 6:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "flowName";
        break;
    case 7:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "numDoc";
        break;
    case 8:
        info.type = List.class;
        info.name = "tabBat";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        codCli = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        break;
    case 1:
        codEmp = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        break;
    case 2:
        codFil = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        break;
    case 3:
        codMot = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        break;
    case 4:
        datCol = value.toString();
        break;
    case 5:
        flowInstanceID = value.toString();
        break;
    case 6:
        flowName = value.toString();
        break;
    case 7:
        numDoc = value.toString();
        break;
    //TODO List?        
    case 8:
        tabBat = (List<CadastrosImpGarInTabBat>) value;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Pesquisando parece que o KvmSerializable aceita `Vector`, porque não troca o `List` para `Vector` e usa o `PropertyInfo.VECTOR_CLASS`?

Comment: Fiz a alteração para VECTOR_CLASS porém continua a não enviar os itens (filhos) da estrutura principal. Alguma outra ideia?

Comment: Atualize o código da pergunta, nunca usei o KvmSerializable, mas pesquisando vi que ele suporta a `Collection` `Vector`, não sabia se iria funcionar.

Comment: Coloque a sua solução em forma de resposta. Deixando separado o que é pergunta e o que é resposta, além de seguir o modelo do site você ainda pode ajudar utilizadores futuros e ganhar pontos de reputação por isso.

Comment: @Math Coloquei a solução dele como resposta da *Community Wiki*

Comment: @Andrey pois então, eu pensei em fazer isso, mas acho que o legal seria esperar um tempo para ver se ele mesmo fazer ia por a resposta, pois senão ele não tem chances de ganhar os pontos né? Agora que já tá feito deixa, mas vamos ver se o OP cria a resposta com autoria dele, se ele fizer daí vc deleta a CW, ok?

Comment: @Math Você está certo, se ele responder eu deleto.

Comment: @felipearon depois que você escrever sua própria resposta (veja como o Andrey fez e faça igual) você poderá aceitar ela. Isso indicará que a pergunta está resolvida, é assim que fazemos aqui. Para mais detalhes veja [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3117)

Comment: @Andrey no problem!

Comment: @Math não entendi direito. De qualquer forma, postei como resposta a solução que encontrei pra contornar o problema.

Comment: @felipearon é que você postou a resposta junto com a pergunta, e a gente costuma separar os dois, tendeu? Se quiser poste sua resposta e aceite ela daí.

Comment: @Math, mas logo abaixo postei como resposta a solução... ou não? Agora tô confuso kkk

Comment: @felipearon foi o Andrey que editou sua pergunta, extraindo sua resposta e colocando no campo de resposta, hehehe.. Ele fez isso para organizar, mas como foi de sua autoria o ideal seria você mesmo fazer isso :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei criando o código "na unha" utilizando **SoapObject**

```
    SoapObject coletaEnv = new SoapObject();
    coletaEnv.addProperty("codCli", coleta.getIdCliente());
    coletaEnv.addProperty("codEmp", 1);
    coletaEnv.addProperty("codFil", 1);
    coletaEnv.addProperty("codMot", coleta.getIdMotorista());
    coletaEnv.addProperty("datCol", DateUtils.dateToString(coleta.getDataHora()));
    coletaEnv.addProperty("numDoc", coleta.getProtocolo());

    for (ColetaItem item : coleta.getBaterias()) {

        SoapObject tabBat = new SoapObject(null, "tabBat");
        tabBat.addProperty("codBar", item.getCodigoBarras());
        tabBat.addProperty("codRef", item.getBateria().getReferencia());
        tabBat.addProperty("datFab", DateUtils.dateToString(item.getDataFabricacao()));
        tabBat.addProperty("datVct", DateUtils.dateToString(item.getDataVencimento()));
        tabBat.addProperty("defOri", item.getDefeito().getDescricao());
        tabBat.addProperty("desDef", item.getDefeito().getDescricao());
        coletaEnv.addSoapObject(tabBat);
    }

    String methodName = "ImpGar";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSBase.NAMESPACE, methodName);
    request.addProperty("user", "user");
    request.addProperty("password", "pass");
    request.addProperty("encryption", 0);

    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("parameters");
    pi.setValue(coletaEnv);
    request.addProperty(pi);
```